# How to ensure a sequence of images is actually displayed on an ImageView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, imageview

I have a single ImageView, properly connected, etc. I display a start image, call a method that processes it and I update the ImageView with the new image, and repeat a couple of times.

So:

```
self.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:"@startImage"];  
// some code
self.imageView.image = [self.imageManipulator grayScaleImage:self.imageView.image]; 
// some code
self.imageView.image = [self.imageManipulator adjustContrast:self.imageView.image]; 
// etc
```

Now each method gets called with the proper image (i.e. the one returned from the previous method) but my problem is that only the final image ends actually being displayed after all the algorithms have finished.

How to I make it so that after each method returns, the intermediate image is put up like I am attempting to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are not giving the system a chance to display your images. What happens is:

You install the first image.

You install the second image.

You install the third image.

Your code returns, the system visits the event loop, and the third image is actually displayed to the screen. The other images are not displayed at all.

What you could do is use a method that delays execution, like performSelector:withObject:afterDelay. Say something like this:

```
//Install the first image into the image view.
UIImage *firstImage =  [UIImage imageNamed:"@startImage"];
self.imageView.image = firstImage;  


//After a brief delay (.1 seconds) install the second image into the image view
UIImage *secondImage =  [self.imageManipulator grayScaleImage: firstImage];
[self.imageView performSelector: @selector(setImage:) withObject: secondImage afterDelay: .1];

//After an additional .1 seconds of delay (.2 seconds total) install the 3rd image
UIImage *thirdImage = [self.imageManipulator adjustContrast: secondImage]; 
[self.imageView performSelector: @selector(setImage:) withObject: thirdImage afterDelay: .2];
```

Comment: This was basically the answer I wanted, I modified it slightly however. Rather than run a delay, I do the computation in the background and the image updates on the main loop. That has performSelectorOnMainThread: (sel) waitUntilDone:YES. So I can wait until the image is installed before going into my next computation. Works perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

If you do those three statements in a row without giving the main run loop a chance, the UI will never update, so you'll just see the final image.  You have to give the run loop a chance to run. Either delay each statement with a timer, or add those image changes as operations to an NSOperationQueue. (There may be other solutions which are more appropriate depending on what "//some code" is)

Answer (score 0):

The value of the `image` property is changed multiple times in one turn of the run loop. The screen isn't redrawn until after all of changes are made. At the point when `UIImageView` redraws, the value of the `image` property is the last `UIImage` it was set to.